# filter out empty files when copying between s3 buckets

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am copying txt files between cross account s3 buckets using python boto3. I am reading files to a pandas data frame to do some cleaning. I notice a lot of files are empty. Is there way to filter out 0B files before copying.

thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an option to check the size on s3 before downloading or want to do that later on after download that particular file?

Comment: Can you show us your code so we can see _how_ you are copying the files?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu I would prefer after downloading from S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list of all files in the bucket and exclude the ones with size 0. An approach is t0 use the following:

1. Make a list of all the files in the bucket and a list of their sizes:

```
session  = Session(aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY)
s3       = session.resource('s3')
bucket   = s3.Bucket(bucket_name_string)
my_files = []
file_size = []
for s3_file in bucket.objects.all():
     my_files.append(s3_file.key)
     file_size.append(s3_file.size)
```

2. Make a dataframe with this information

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'file name': my_files,
     'file size': file_size
    })
```

which would return something like:

```
                                           file name  file size
0                                            apc/daily/          0
1           apc/daily/2021/1/dagsrapport-2021-01-18.csv       1498
2           apc/daily/2021/1/dagsrapport-2021-01-19.csv       1498
3           apc/daily/2021/1/dagsrapport-2021-01-20.csv       1500
4           apc/daily/2021/1/dagsrapport-2021-01-21.csv       1498
...                                                 ...        ...
7829  apc/vehicles/2021/4/814/0814-2021-04-19T020101...         70
7830  apc/vehicles/2021/4/814/0814-2021-04-20T020131...       8741
7831  apc/vehicles/2021/4/814/0814-2021-04-21T020128...       8719
7832  apc/vehicles/2021/4/814/0814-2021-04-22T020127...       7337
7833  apc/vehicles/2021/4/814/0814-2021-04-23T020117...       9292
```

3. Pick the ones that have the size you want:

```
df_non_empty = df[df['file size']>0]
List_non_empty = df_non_empty['file name'].to_list()
```

4. Use this list to pick those files to transfer och copy between buckets.

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly and I am now able to copy files > 0B to my destination bucket.

Comment: Glad it helped!